# How can I sort a dataframe by a predetermined order of factor levels in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I have a data frame in which one column consists of unique factors. I want to sort this data frame by a predefined order of factor levels, independend of the original order.

For example my data looks like this:

```
label <- c('tree','lake','house', 'human')

number <- c(50,1,2,5)


df <- data.frame(

  group = label,

  value = number)

category_order <- category_order = c('tree','house','lake','human')
```

where df has the form

```
     group number
1    tree  50
2    lake   1
3    house  2
4    human  5
```

but I would like it to be sorted in like category_oder so df_new looks like:

```
     group number
1    tree  50
2    house  2
3    lake   1
4    human  5
```

I know know that in this case I could just swap the second and third row, but in general I don't know in which order the facors will be in the data frame and I couldn't find a way to do this without having strong restrictions about what factors I can use and the order in which they shoud be in the end. (for example alphabetical order)

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(group = sort(factor(group, levels = category_order)))`

Comment: This indeed changes the order of "group" the way I wanted it to, but the values in "number" stay in the same row. I want the 2 to stay in the same row as house.

Comment: sorry, I thought you want to break the. order.  Updated as a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the `levels` of the 'group' as `category_order` and that use that to `arrange

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
          arrange(factor(group, levels = category_order))
df1
#  group value
#1  tree    50
#2 house     2
#3  lake     1
#4 human     5
```

---

Or using `fct_relevel`

```
library(forcats)
df %>% 
   arrange(fct_relevel(group, category_order))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `match` to get the order of `group` based on `category_order`

```
df[match(df$group, category_order), ]

#  group value
#1  tree    50
#3 house     2
#2  lake     1
#4 human     5
```